# Does Blender no longer support Make Human file format?

Tags: import, file-format, makehuman

Does Blender no longer support the use of Make Human file format MHX1?

The file type is changed from mhx to dae and the mhx file type no longer shows up in Blender as a supported file type. I mention this as I see some creators
point out the changing of Blender settings in their tutorial videos that no longer match the current configuration and it makes it more confusing .

Answer (score 6):

The MHX1 format is extremely old and has been deprecated (in favor of MHX2) for many years. MHX1 should not be used, and no modern version of MakeHuman supports it.

Contrary to MHX1, MHX2 is an add-on that needs to be installed. It is not bundled with Blender.

How to get MHX2 support is answered in a MakeHuman FAQ, see http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/FAQ:What_happened_to_the_MHX_export_in_MH_1.1.x_and_later%3F

Quick summary:

- In a Blender + MakeHuman 1.1.x setup, you need to install MHX2 from https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/overview
- In a Blender + MakeHuman 1.2.x (currently in alpha) setup, both the MH side and Blender side of MHX2 are shipped with the MakeHuman zip.

Comment: thank you have been working the problem and will take all the advice I can get

Comment: on a semi related topic if you go to the makehuman side ,http://www.makehumancommunity.org/targets.html   To get the full effect of MakeHuman go to the targets page ,
( these are all slide modifiers too add to makehuman  , add them to :
your PC: C\user\your AKA\documents\makehuman\v1\data\custom ,
it will add a huge amount of functionality to the makehuman  creation side. Please note I downloaded the program and unzipped it to a folder on my desktop and after using it it placed a makehuman file in the above location where the program is drawing its information from.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed out on the Blender side ,left click upper left corner for scroll down menu .pick user preference ,Ctrl\alt\U ,go to center tab user panel,
pick add-ons, add files and activate with check , save user preference , go to 
makehuman side find plugin folder add plugins.have loaded the files into 3
zip files per file  in a master file for Blender and MH side for anyone that wants them and are having a problem getting them just email me ,they cover MHX2 and DAE , thanks all.